# is Cloud loadbalancer necessary?

Tags: azure, load-balancing, kubernetes, cloud, nginx-ingress

I currently have a Kubernetes cluster in the cloud AKS, and I'm using nginx-ingress to load balance, define routing rules and manage how traffic gets to my services. I see that many people are using cloud load balancers for advanced stuff like multi-region load balancing but I still don't understand how they fit in the picture for a single region. Adding to that a standard loadbalancer comes by default with an AKS cluster. Is it necessary ?

So my questions is What are the benefits of cloud load balancer when using Kubernetes in the cloud with nginx-ingress for a single region? Don't they do the same thing?

Comment: Can you please define the service what you me with cloud balancer? Are you referring to an application gateway or Azure traffic manager?

Comment: Cloud loadbalancer is a loadbalancer service provided by cloud providers to balance the load on the user's infrastrcture. in the case of azure it provides two types the standard tier and basic tier. And Services, I mean application or Kubernetes service. Since I am using Nginx-ingress to route the traffic to those internal application/services in the cluster. Is it really neccessary to have a cloud loadbalancer ? ( because they are enabled by default and they cost money )

Comment: Instead of a cloud load balancer I would recommend looking into a application gateway or front door. Depending on the workload but a application gateway is a much better choice in my opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is needed.
nGinx is load balancing traffic across your services in AKS, but the cloud provider load balancer is load balancing traffic across nodes in your cluster. These are two different services and both are needed.

Comment: "Nginx is load balancing traffic across your services in AKS" and the services will balance the traffic to the pods depending on how many replicas are present. Those pods can exist in diffrent nodes so doesnt this mean that the services also load balance the traffic accross the pods nodes in the cluster ? Could you please clarify this more or correct me if I am wrong ?

Comment: Nginix is load balancing across your services, it has no concept of what node they live on and the underlying VMs, when it load balances across your services, under the hood the cloud load balncer is load balancing this traffic across your nodes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a cloud load balancer I would recommend looking into a application gateway or front door. Depending on the workload, a application gateway is a much better choice in my opinion. Because it also allows to integrate a WAF(Web Application Firewall) for security. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-overview